# как убрать тень сверху?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Открываю по кнопке новую активность, ставлю ей NoTitleBar и в итоге в самом верху темная полоска типа тень. Как убрать? или хоть куда копать то, в какую сторону?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если смотреть на фоне белой активности лучше видно 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот разметка второй активности которая появляется поверх первой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    tools:context="com.evico.sdfsfgs.Main2Activity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.evico.sdfsfgs">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme.test"
              >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

стили

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.test">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

UPD: загрузил приложение на телефон (дроид 7.0) там все белое, никаких теней, возможно ли, что это косяк эмулятора? использую Genymotion.

Comment: Покажите разметку

Comment: Покажите, что у Вас в стилях. Конкретно в `AppTheme.test`